# Check if all words from text line match RegEx elements (guitar chords)

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to achieve the following:

1) Check if every word (in this case guitar chord) from a text line is contained in RegEx. All words/characters must match.

2) If yes, I want every single word from that line to become a link, pointing to an URL customized by the word itself.

I.E. The following line:

```
Am   Bb  C# Dadd9
Song lyrics here
```

should become this:

```
<a href="example.com/Am">Am</a>   <a href="example.com/Bb">Bb</a>  <a href="example.com/C#">C#</a> <a href="example.com/Dadd9">Dadd9</a>
Song lyrics here
```

My RegEx (notes and symbols forming each chord):

```
var lineRegex = /^\s*(?:(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|A#|C#|D#|F#|G#|Ab|Bb|Db|Eb|Gb){1}(?:m|\+|\-|aug|dim|add|b|#|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|\/)*\s*)+$/;
```

Here's what I've com up to for step 2:

```
var text = $('.input').val();   //get text
var lines = text.split('\n');   //split text into lines
var chords = lines.split(' ');  //split lines into chords

var link = "http://www.example.com/";
      $.each(chords, function(index, value) {   //append link to chord
        $('.output').append('<a href="' + link + value + '">' + value + '</a> ');
      });
```

I can't achieve step 1. How do I check if a text line contains only notes and symbols from RegEx?

Comment: Be careful when using `#` in an url, as it is an special character, and should be encoded as `%25`.  Something similar happens to `+` (which should be encoded as `%2B`, and `/` (which should be encoded as `%2F`)  (letter case is significant, so be careful to use uppercase hex digits)  Also use `\<` and `\>` as anchors in your regexp, instead of using `\s`, as they anchor to word boundaries, making spaces not required at the sides of your chords.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

### Brief

I have no idea what chords are valid/invalid on a guitar, and since you haven't specified that information (in clear text - without implemented regex), and we aren't certain that your regex works, I'm basing my answer off of this random chart I found ([first result on Google images for *list of all guitar chords*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=list%20of%20all%20guitar%20chords&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicjJma3rHWAhUC0YMKHV7SDCgQ_AUICigB&biw=958&bih=954)).

[image]

---

### Regex

#### Sample 1

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/d4RdKT/1)

Based on this chart, I've created the following regex

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<chord_A>A(?:b(?:[679+]|sus)?|m[67]?|[689]|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)
  (?<chord_B>B(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)
  (?<chord_C>C(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim))?)
  (?<chord_D>D(?:b(?:[679+]|maj7|sus)?|[679]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)
  (?<chord_E>E(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)
  (?<chord_F>F(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:[79]|m[67]|dim)?)?)
  (?<chord_G>G(?:b(?:maj7|sus|[6+])?|[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim))?)
  (?<chords>(?&chord_A)|(?&chord_B)|(?&chord_C)|(?&chord_D)|(?&chord_E)|(?&chord_F))
)
(?<link>\b(?&chords)(?=\s|$))
```

In this regex, I've defined groups according to chords' starting letter (e.g. `A`).

This regex works by defining all possible instances of each chord (in each group `chord_X` where `X` represents the chord, i.e. `C`). The defined group `chords` is a comparison between each chord (e.g. `Chord A` or `Chord B` or ...). The final regex uses `(?<link>\b(?&chords)(?=\s|$))`. This regex ensures that a word boundary character exists before the chord (each begins with a letter so this will not fail), and is followed by either a space  or the end of the string `$` (`\b` cannot be used here since some notes include word boundary characters - such as `#`, thus, to properly catch these instances, we use spaces or EOF).

#### Sample 2

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/d4RdKT/2)

Note that since `C#` doesn't exist in the image (unless I'm blind), it won't catch `C#` from your input. You can change this behaviour by using the following regex instead (which just adds a `?` at the end of `\#(?:m[67]?|dim)` in the `chord_C` defined group.

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<chord_A>A(?:b(?:[679+]|sus)?|m[67]?|[689]|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)
  (?<chord_B>B(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)
  (?<chord_C>C(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim)?)?)
  (?<chord_D>D(?:b(?:[679+]|maj7|sus)?|[679]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)
  (?<chord_E>E(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)
  (?<chord_F>F(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:[79]|m[67]|dim)?)?)
  (?<chord_G>G(?:b(?:maj7|sus|[6+])?|[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim))?)
  (?<chords>(?&chord_A)|(?&chord_B)|(?&chord_C)|(?&chord_D)|(?&chord_E)|(?&chord_F))
)
(?<link>\b(?&chords)(?=\s|$))
```

---

### Substitution

```
<a href="example.com/${link}">${link}</a>
```

The substitution makes reference to the named capture group from our regex `link`.

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Am   Bb  C# Dadd9
Song lyrics here
```

#### Sample 1 - Output

```
<a href="example.com/Am">Am</a>   <a href="example.com/Bb">Bb</a>  C# Dadd9
Song lyrics here
```

#### Sample 2 - Output

```
<a href="example.com/Am">Am</a>   <a href="example.com/Bb">Bb</a>  <a href="example.com/C#">C#</a> Dadd9
Song lyrics here
```

---

## Edit

Since javascript doesn't use PCRE regex, you can't use named capture groups as the above suggests, so, unfortunately, we're going to have to use a beautiful long and unreadable regex as follows...

```
(\b(?:(?:A(?:b(?:[679+]|sus)?|m[67]?|[689]|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)|(?:B(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)|(?:C(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim)?)?)|(?:D(?:b(?:[679+]|maj7|sus)?|[679]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|\+|sus)?)|(?:E(?:b(?:[679+]|sus|m[67]?|maj7|dim)?|m[67]?|[679+]|maj7|dim|sus)?)|(?:F(?:[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:[79]|m[67]|dim)?)?)|(?:G(?:b(?:maj7|sus|[6+])?|[679+]|m[67]?|maj7|dim|sus|\#(?:m[67]?|dim))?))(?=\s|$))
```

With `<a href="example.com/$1">$1</a>` as the substitution.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Since I'm not an expert, I don't recognize your regex as a jquery array like mine was (php maybe?). Am I missing something or there is a way to convert its definition to jquery? I want to use it in a .js file

Comment: So now I'm defining you chord_X as "var chord_A = ..." for each one. I don't get how to convert "(?<link>\b(?&chords)(?=\s|$))" to jquery

Comment: @AlbertoMoneti I've added an edit to my post. JavaScript doesn't use PCRE regex (like PHP does), and so some functionality is not available. The edit I've added is a long and bloated version of the original code without the nice structure that was defined.

Comment: @AlbertoMoneti the regex structures I've set in my answer are not to be confused with javascript code, the entire block of code is, in fact, regular expression code, thus, you should not be pulling it apart/piecing it together using javascript - it's one unit of regex.